# Mediawiki interlanguage homepage

Tags: mediawiki

I am trying to create homepage like wikipedia.org for multilanguage mediawiki sites, how is it possible to implement, to get search for all languages and count of articles in each mediawiki?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source for that page comes from [the page *www.wikipedia.org template* on Wikimedia meta-wiki](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Www.wikipedia.org_template). Things like article counts seem to be updated manually.

The form to search a Wikipedia in the selected article uses [search-redirect.php](https://github.com/wikimedia/operations-mediawiki-config/blob/master/search-redirect.php).